# Function on dependent type is not total, but idris thinks that it's total

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I have a `Vehicle` type depending on a `PowerSource` type:

```
data PowerSource = Petrol | Pedal | Electric

data Vehicle : PowerSource -> Type where
  Unicycle : Vehicle Pedal
  Motorcycle : (fuel: Nat) -> Vehicle Petrol
  Tram: (battery : Nat) -> Vehicle Electric
```

and a function `wheels`. `Tram` is an unhandled case.

```
wheels : Vehicle power -> Nat
wheels Unicycle = 1
wheels Motorcycle = 2
```

When I check the total-ness of `wheels` from the REPL,

```
:total wheels
Main.wheels is Total
```

As I did not handle the `Tram` type in `wheels`, I don't understand how `wheels` can be total. Am I misunderstanding what 'total' mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because in `wheels Motorcycle` it's treating `Motorcycle` as a variable, because it isn't well typed as a constructor application - `Motorcycle` the constructor takes an argument.

The fact that this gets past the type checker is quite surprising, and I think this is actually a (fixable) mistake in the design of Idris. To avoid this kind of error, I think it should only allow pattern variables to be automatically bound if they begin with a lower case letter, in much the same way as type variables are bound.

Comment: OMG this is a horrible feature to have. Does this also mean with `data Vehicle: PowerSource -> Type where Unicycle: Vehicle Pedal; Motorcycle: Vehicle Petrol; Tram: Vehicle Electricity`, a function like `total wheels : Vehicle Pedal -> Nat; wheels Unicycle = 1; wheels Motorcycle = 2` will typecheck the same way?

Comment: In that example, the constructors don't take arguments so they would type check fine as applications to the constructor, and so `wheels` wouldn't be total. As I say, this is, er, an accidental feature which is another way of saying a mistake. We should fix it soon.